# Expand power of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-manipulation

I'm very new to *Mathematica*, so excuse my innocence.  I have the following expression:

$$ \left( \sum_{n=0}^r \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} y^n \right)^f $$

I would like *Mathematica* to expand out the expression in powers of $y$, as a polynomial, where $r$ and $f$ are arbitrary positive integers.  Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.

Comment: Take the result from a given *r, f* (here called *result*),  then `Series[result, {y, Infinity, 0}] // Normal`

Comment: That will give an expression in terms of specific $r$,$f$.  I desire an expression for general $r$ and $f$...In other words ungiven.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A bit complicated, this one:

```
With[{m = 5, r = 3}, 
     CoefficientList[Sum[(-x)^n/n!, {n, 0, m}]^r, x] == 
     Table[Sum[FactorialPower[r, k]
               BellY[n, k, Table[(-1)^i, {i, m}]],
               {k, 0, r}]/n!, {n, 0, m r}]]
   True
```

Recall that the [partial Bell polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials) are a way to express [Faà di Bruno's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula), which applies here since the coefficients of a polynomial are the same as the successive derivatives of a polynomial divided by an appropriate factorial. There may be a less cumbersome closed form; I'll keep trying to look.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that!  A very good idea, I will examine it more closely.